# PDF File should be open after authentication only ( client side )

Tags: asp.net, pdf, iis

I have a pdf URL ( `https://<<localhost>>/foldername/pdfname.pdf` ) this should be run after authentication using login page.but it opens always, even without logged in. while try to open using address bar directly.

```
 window.open(<<URL>>, "_blank", 
  "height=800,width=850,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes, menubar=no,location=no");
```

i am using IdSrv authentication (oAuthConfig) for Login. so it should redirct to that login page if it is not authenticated or authorized.

Comment: So you need to use .htaccess to protect foldername. Also remove the space in your parameters

Comment: i hosted in IIS. i tried URL Rewriting in web config. but how can solve this using URLRewrite???

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: i am using Identity server integration with my applicaion. so i enabled the anonymous authentication in IIS8. first it will redirect to login page in idserver. it will return the redirect URL once authenticated successfully.